# Documentation for ~/.config/autostart/ *.desktop entries 12.04

Tags: 12.04, autostart, documentation

I'm using 12.04 LTS.  I'm trying to run a python script as an autostart but it acts abnormally (but works perfectly when started via terminal or IDLE).  I'm beginning to suspect that something in the `.desktop` file could be playing a role.  I'm looking for documentation for `*.desktop` files located in `~/.config/autostart/` or even a broader description of the whole autostart process.  I would like to know what the supported line items are in the `*.desktop` files and the possible settings for each.  Is there a man page that covers this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you are looking for is [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) and especially [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know where to find the "X-GNOME"-specific options documentation?

Comment: @JB0x2D1 Unfortunately I don't know and my google-fu didn't help either. The GNOME guys' pages only reference that freedesktop page for the specifications and that freedesktop page only say that `X-` are extended specifications. :(

Comment: @JB0x2D1 But most of the specific X-GNOME- entries can be found out what they mean, one-by-one, just a complete list is not available (or at least I can't find it.)